# Do intermediate async functions not have to always be wrapped with `async` keyword in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

In the code example below function `a` returns a promise. Using `await` after return is [useless](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-return-await) but I thought (and according to the [examples](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-return-await)) the function returning the promise should still be an `async` function. However, even if I don't add `async` keyword to `a` it still works if it's `await`ed in function `b`. If I don't await `a()` inside `b` then `bRes` is a promise object and not `5`. So this means that I can have an infinite number of functions like `a` which return promise and as long as the first function that calls this infinite chain `await`s the result, then I don't need to wrap the intermediate functions with `async`?

```
const getPromise = () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('promise finished')
    resolve(5)
  }, 2000)
})

const a = () => {
  console.log('from a')
  return getPromise()
}

const b = async () => {
  const bRes = await a()
  console.log('bRes', bRes)
}

b()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No function need to use the `async` keyword unless the `await` keyword is used within it.

The `await` keyword will not work if used outside of functions marked with `async`. And that's **the only** technical use of the `async` keyword (if you want to use it for documentation purposes it's fine but it does nothing otherwise).

All other functions be they synchronous, promise generators, event handlers, observer handlers or just plain old callbacks don't need to be marked with `async` (unless you use await within them).

Comment: are you sure that `async` does "does nothing otherwise"? If I wrap a promise in 5 async functions, for example: `async function a() {return Promise.resolve()}
async function b() {return a()}
b()

function c() {return Promise.resolve()}
async function d() {return c()}
d()` wouldn't it take longer to perform function `d` because it would have to resolve 2 promises instead of only one as in `b`?

Comment: Well, not exactly nothing. It makes the function return a promise. But if the function is already a promise returning function it does nothing otherwise. You can assume "needing to resolve a promise" to take zero CPU time (or at least as slow as `+` or `return` or array indexing - promises does not involve processing at all. It does not create a thread, it does not make a syscall, it does not communicate anything with the OS. Promises is just a design pattern just like MVC is a design pattern

Answer (score 2):

- You can only use `await` inside a function that is `async`
- A function that is `async` will return a promise
- Other means (such as `new Promise`) can be used to create a promise
- You can only (usefully) `await` a promise

Since `a()` returns a promise, and `b` is `async`, you can `await` the return value of `a()` inside `b`.